# PHP - Cache arrays saved in included files or not?

Tags: php, arrays, caching

Should I use cache to store arrays that are saved in included files? include("filename.php");.. Those included files only have arrays and are about 2 to 5 kilobytes so they are pretty small.

But in term of performance, what is the best? Use cache or simply use include? Just to let you know, I use APC cache.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Put simply, try it out. Benchmark it somehow and see what the differences are. I know you're asking about which should theoretically be better and why, but that's the only means of obtaining practical conclusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrays hardcoded in those PHP files are already cached, both by APC and probably also by your OS file cache. No need to duplicate it somewhere else.

Comment: I though that APC wouldn't cache variables and arrays. (as this could cause problems with user-specific data, e.g. in a private account page where every user has it's personal info). In order for a variable or array to be stored in the cache I though I had to use apc_store function... Am I wrong?

Comment: I am just asking because yesterday I asked about APC and variables and I was answered that APC does not cache arrays and variables, it does if we use the funciton apc_store and APC also caches the bytecode. And you are telling me the opposite, at least for the arrays. I just want to make sure I understand correctly. Thanks

Comment: It sounded like you were saying the arrays of data are hardcoded into PHP files. If that's the case, then the data is in the code, and the code is cached. If you actually meant that the included files just contain code which constructs arrays based on some other data (user input, a database, etc) then that data would not be automatically cached by APC.